Is bootstrapping inherently Frequentist? If so, how do we do a Bayesian non-parametric two-sample test?
I normally use frequentist statistics but I now want to use Bayesian statistics as I want to carry out a two-sample (randomised control trial) test that includes prior information. I have an existing two-group sample and plan to collect a second two-group sample, which I would analyse for group differences, using the group differences from the first sample as the prior. (The reasons I want to do that are here but I don't think most of what's there is relevant for the current question.)
My problem is this. My standard go-to for Frequentist two-sample testing is bootstrapping the confidence interval on the differences for the means. I think this is usually better than a t-test because of having thrown out most (all?) of the parametric assumptions. But my searches for a Bayesian equivalent turn up nothing relevant. There are search results for e.g. non-parametric Bayesian or Bayesian bootstrap but they are about much more complex scenarios than a two-sample test.
I don't yet understand the Bayesian approach well but I don't see why it would inherently need to make assumptions about my data distributions. Are there methods that would give me a Bayes factor for my two-sample comparison without making parametric assumptions about the data distribution? If not, why not?
Some notes:

The question is mainly to help me understand the theory, but I want to get the analysis done, and so I welcome recommendations for R code.

A further complication is that my data is survey data with sample weights.

My existing sample has n=500+500 and my second sample also would.



Theoretical justification for the bootstrap in frequentist analysis isn't exactly a piece of cake, and I remember I have seen asymptotical results that looked like it would need very similar assumptions to the Central Limit Theorem to work - which is the same situation in which a standard t-test will work as well (for large enough samples such as 2*500 appeal to the CLT is fine and there's not much worry about non-normality, unless there's worry for the bootstrap, too).

Check https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/447532/7224

Thanks, both these comments were useful, especially the link - it seems this is a thing, just a bit niche.

The CLT may be far from fine for N < 50,000 + if the data distribution is noticeably asymmetric.

There are at least two natural Bayesian approaches to this problem:

The Bayesian $t$-test which relaxes the normality and equal variance assumptions
The Bayesian Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney 2-sample rank-sum test

These are both exemplified here.  Since the Wilcoxon test is a very special case of the proportional odds semiparametric ordinal logistic model, the Bayesian Wilcoxon test follows from fitting a Bayesian proportional odds model.  Details are here.
Sampling weights add complexities to all this, and are often not necessary.  For example it's not a good idea to weight on something you are not averaging over, i.e., if you condition on a covariate upon which weights were based, you've got the conditional estimates you need and the weights would just inflate the variance of estimated values.
Bayesian is pretty much frequentist, and its success (unless using the double bootstrap) pretty much depends on the similarity between the bootstrap distribution and the sampling distribution.  I think of the bootstrap as a "poor man Bayesian solution" in a way, and prefer to use flexible and semiparametric models in a Bayesian framework.  I keep getting disappointed with the accuracy of bootstrap confidence intervals.
